Automatically refreshing table from google cloud storage
I have monthly CSV files in google cloud storage in a single bucket with the same schema and I want these all in a table in BigQuery.
I've batch loaded them into a single table using the standard add table procedure with a wildcard to bring all the CSVs.
Is there a way that the table can automatically refresh when new data is added without me manually needing to press refresh or deleting and recreating the table.
Thanks in advance
So far have struggled to get close

You can use Cloud Functions to write a storage trigger that fires when an object is added to the bucket.  You will need to write the code to refresh the table when that happens.

In your story, you are loading the data into BigQuery table.  This means that you are copying the data from GCS into BigQuery and BigQuery is storing the data in its native storage.  An alternative is to use GCS as the storage.  If you define your BigQuery Table as either an "external" table or leverage the BigLake service, you can define the table as a pointer or reference to the GCS bucket/folder.  When a query is submitted to BigQuery for execution, BigQuery will then use the data that is found in GCS to satisfy the query.  The implication of this is that the data is never copied into BigQuery and what is actually available in GCS at the time of the query is used to satisfy the query.  If new files are added to the GCS storage, they will instantly be included in the next query.
So ... your question asked "is there a way that the table can automatically refresh when new data is added ..." ... while this story is not a load the table answer ... it does seem to offer a notion of what I believe to be the desired outcome ... which is to have new data included in subsequent queries.
The downside of the proposal is that queries referencing external data might be a little slower.  I'd suggest that you search on external tables and BigLake to see pros and cons.
